# Can't ping any websites, but can access websites through browser

Tags: wireless, networking, macbook-pro, ping

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 running on the newest version of Macbook Pro (dual boot). I'm using wireless connection to access websites through the Chrome browser and it works. But `ping` doesn't work. For example, this is the output

```
$ping -c 3 www.google.com
PING www.google.com (74.125.226.212) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2015ms
```

It seems that it is not the issue of name resolving. So what could be wrong? I'm not using a proxy for my browser.

This is the output of tracepath

```
$ tracepath www.google.com
1:  <my machine name>.local                                     0.052ms pmtu 1500
1:  no reply
2:  no reply
3:  no reply
...
    Too many hops: pmtu 1500
    Resume: pmtu 1500
```

EDIT:
After re-installing Ubuntu, ping works again.

Answer (score 6):

From `man ping`: `ping  uses  the  ICMP  protocol's  mandatory ECHO_REQUEST datagram to elicit an ICMP ECHO_RESPONSE from a host or gateway`.

Your browser opens a `TCP` connection on port `80`.

Any system along the path between you and `www.google.com` could be deciding to treat these two connections differently.

You could use `tracepath` (from the `iputils-tracepath` package) to see which systems are in that path, then `ping`, or `hping3` to explore.

FWIW, I get PING responses from `www.google.com`,(`-c 3` limits `ping` to 3 `ICMP` packets, which IMHO, is more polite):

```
walt@aardvark:~(0)$ ping -c 3 www.google.com  

PING www.google.com (74.125.225.114) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ord08s08-in-f18.1e100.net (74.125.225.114): icmp_req=1 ttl=56 time=35.9 ms
64 bytes from ord08s08-in-f18.1e100.net (74.125.225.114): icmp_req=2 ttl=56 time=32.1 ms
64 bytes from ord08s08-in-f18.1e100.net (74.125.225.114): icmp_req=3 ttl=56 time=32.0 ms

--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 32.096/33.402/35.964/1.817 ms
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: It shows the difference in the two methods of connection (ping uses Internet control Message Protocol https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol, and browsers use Transmission Control Protocol https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol . It offers tools by which the OP can investigate further into the problem (ICMP fails TCP works), offers a philosophical belief (-c 3) and shows that www.google.com does respond to ICMP Ping requests for one system. Can you suggest improvements? This is what I would do if I were at OP's keyboard.

Comment: This response doesn't answer OP question in any way.

Comment: It explains how "Can't Ping" and "can access websites" use different protocols (ICMP vs TCP) and may evoke different responses. How would you improve the response?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure whether this may answer your Question.

but it may happen that you didn't update the proxy in "settings/network"
If you gave the proxy in manual proxy in mozilla, and not in settings/network
you will be able to access websites with browser but you will not be able to ping any site

Comment: I'm not using a proxy in my browser.

Comment: apt-get update is woking in your terminal ?I was about to ask about traceroute map.. It seems your apt-get is working

Comment: apt-get was working. I just re-installed Ubuntu and ping works again.

Answer (score -1):

your firewall or proxy server just left HTTP protocol for you so yo can browse but cannot ping any website or ip. you need to have other protocol such az ftp, UDP TCP/IP and etc to ping correctly.